# Resetting global state of composable between tests

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-composition-api

I'm using a composable with global state

```js
const state = ref([]);

export function useFoo() { 
  const loadFoos = async () => {
    const data = await fetch(...)
    state.value = await data.json();
  }

   return {
    state: readonly(state), //readonly!
    loadFoos
   }
}
```

Now I want to test this composable with jest. First testcase should secure if the right api has been called. Second testcase if the state has been populated with the data.
However the second testcase fails, because of the singleton pattern. The state is still populated with the testdata of the first test.

```js
describe("useFoos", () => {
    const data = { data: "data" };
    beforeEach(() => {
      jest.resetModules();
      fetch.mockResolvedValue([data]);
    });

    it("calls api", async () => {
      const { state, loadFoos } = useFoos();
      await loadFoos();
      expect(fetch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });

    it("stores values", async () => {
      const { state, loadFoos } = useRoutes();
      // this fails because of the singleton pattern of the global state composable
      // state.value is not [], instead it its [data]
      expect(state.value).toEqual([]); 

      await loadFoos();
      expect(state.value).toEqual([data]);
    });
  });
```

I've read, that I could implement a `reset` function. However I don't want to add this to my productive code. Another option i tried is reimport the module for each test with `jest.isolateModules`, but that didn't work either.

Anyone got an idea how can I reset `state.value` for each test?

Comment: Why not reset the state after the expect function was called at the end of your it block. Another approach would be to call the composable outside of `it` and reset it in the after each

Comment: What I forgot to add to my pseudocode is that the composable only returns a `readonly` variable. So how would you do it without adding a reset function to your productive code?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've did it using `jest.isolateModules` with `require` instead of import:

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  jest.isolateModules(() => {
    myModule = require("./useFoo.");
  });
});

it("working test", () => {
  const { state } = myModule.useRoutes();
  expect(state.value).toEqual([]);
}

it("previously failed test", () => {
  const { state } = myModule.useRoutes();
  expect(state.value).toEqual([]); // this is now working 
}
```

This ensures that the module is reimported before each test, which initializes the singleton/state again.